# Indicating multiple value in a Dict[] for type hints

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I express the type of a `Dict` which has two keys that take two different types of values? For example:

```
a = {'1': [], '2': {})
```

The following is just to give you an idea of what I am looking for.

> Dict[(str, List), (str, Set)]

Comment: This is not support in [most] statically typed language either. Consider a Union (eg. "Record" or "Tuple") to decompose the types.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The feature you are asking about is called **"Heterogeneous dictionaries"** where you need to define specific types of values for the specific keys. The issue was being discussed at [Type for heterogeneous dictionaries with string keys](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/28) and is now made available in Python 3.8. You can now use the `TypedDict` which will allow a syntax like:

```
class HeterogeneousDictionary(TypedDict):
    x: List
    y: Set
```

---

For older Python versions, at the very least, we can ask for values to be either `List` or `Set` using [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

```
from typing import Dict, List, Set, Union

def f(a: Dict[str, Union[List, Set]]):
    pass
```

This is, of course, not ideal as we lose a lot of information about what keys need to have values of which types.

Comment: [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) was added in Python 3.8. The answer should be updated.